# Swagger UI Express plugin issue with webpack bundling in production mode

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, swagger

I have included `swagger-ui-express` plugin in my node `express` REST API. While bundling with `webpack` in production mode, I am receiving as error such as `SwaggerUIBundle` is not defined. Without `webpack` my app is working fine. Can someone help me on configuring `webpack` for `swagger-ui-express`

[image: Stack Trace Error Message]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, there's still a [known issue](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/90) on `swagger-ui-express` when it comes to `Webpack`. So there is still no official fix for it. For the workaround, we include the `dist` artifacts of `swagger-ui-express` to our build artifact (done by `webpack`) and deploy it together with our `server.js` (or whatever is your main file).

You need to install `CopyWebpackPlugin`

> npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev

And include this configuration to your `webpack.config`

```
node: {
    __dirname: false
},
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-16x16.png',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png'
        ]
    })
]
```

Comment: I hope this works.   Same problem and its 2024.

Comment: @Dave have you tried it? Prolly you can update us.